# Difference between same material

Tags: materials

I have download a Rust Material from free website. I just copied the object and paste in new file. Add a default sphere and applied the same rust material on it. Will i get much difference between both the material.

[image]

[image]

Original material look much solid and some few rust spots on it. With compare to my sphere its having much rust and not a solid look transparent in between. May i know the reason why the difference between same material show difference on my object.

Comment: If you look at the material node setup it's making use of some geometry data. If you make extrudes in the sphere you get those spots as well.

Comment: @Sidar what about the transparency my sphere is to transparent then the original mesh

Comment: It's using a transparency shader to achieve those holes. If you don't want that you can probably just kill the transparency connection. It seems like transparency happens when it's full on rust. If you turn off the subsurf on that model transparency will appear also. Seems like you need some good density to prevent transparency

Comment: Made a new sphere made sure it had more density : https://i.imgur.com/Opl1XJl.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not entirely sure how it exactly works but it's mostly affected by the following I believe:

[image]

Based on the geometry information the value for rust and holes ( transparency ) is calculated. I've noticed that if the density is lower it tends to be more rusty/transparent.

[image]

Here is some info on the pontiness: [the Pointiness value, dissected](https://blenderartists.org/t/the-pointiness-value-dissected/674328)